# Paginação de registros

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

Estou tentando criar uma tabela dentro de uma janela modal que é acionada / aberta a medida que o usuário clica em um botão, mas devido ter muitos registros fica lento para abrir, portanto pensei em paginar. Alguém poderia me mostrar algum exemplo ?

```
    <!-- INICIO DA JANELA MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_afil" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <label class="modal-title">Afiliada</label>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">
                            <div class="page-header">
                                <div class="row"><!-- Inicio Cria DIV para efetuar pesquisa dos registros -->
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                        <form id='ajax_form' class="form-inline ajax_form" method="GET" action="pesquisar_1.php">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="exampleInputName2">Pesquisar</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="pesquisar" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Digitar...">
                                            </div>
                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- Fim Cria DIV para efetuar pesquisa dos registros -->

                                <!-- Inicio da Paginacao de Resultados -->
                                <nav class="text-center">
                                    <?php
                                        //Verificar a pagina anterior e posterior
                                        $pagina_anterior = $pagina - 1;
                                        $pagina_posterior = $pagina + 1;
                                    ?>

                                    <ul class="pagination">
                                        <li>
                                                <?php
                                                if($pagina_anterior != 0){ ?>
                                                        <a href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                                        </a>
                                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                                        <?php }  ?>
                                        </li>
                                        <?php 
                                        //Apresentar a paginacao
                                        for($i = 1; $i < $num_pagina + 1; $i++){ ?>
                                                <li><a href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        <li>
                                                <?php
                                                if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){ ?>
                                                        <a href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                                        </a>
                                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                                        <?php }  ?>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>                                 
                                </nav>
                                <!-- Fim da Paginacao de Resultados -->

                                <!-- Inicio Tabela com registros que aparece dentro do Modal -->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <table class='table table-bordered' class='pagination'>                    
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><b>Código</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Nome Fantasia</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Codigo Interno</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Nome / Razão Social</b></td>
                                                <td><b>Endereço</b></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <?php while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_cursos)){ ?>
                                        <tbody>    
                                            <tr class='btn-default'>    
                                                <td class='get-cadcli'><?php echo $rows_cursos['codigo']; ?></td>
                                                <td class='get-value-cadcli'><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome_fantasia']; ?></td>
                                                <td class='get-value-cadcli'><?php echo $rows_cursos['codigo_interno']; ?></td>
                                                <td class='get-value-cadcli'><?php echo $rows_cursos['cliente']; ?></td>
                                                <td class='get-value-cadcli'><?php echo $rows_cursos['nome_logr']; ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Inicio Tabela com registros que aparece dentro do Modal -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FIM DA JANELA MODAL -->
```

Comment: Existe a possibilidade de fazer o que quiser e onde quiser, caso esteja com dificuldade, poste o codigo do que já tentou e ai, tentamos ajudar.

Comment: então no caso eu tento fazer a paginação porém mexi tanto no script que agora ele só fica travado na primeira página e não vai para as outras quando eu seleciono, vou postar o código

Comment: @RafaelAugusto editei a pergunta com o código poderia analisar

Comment: Se você fizer paginação com `php` nunca vai funcionar, já que sempre ira atualizar a pagina, você tem que fazer com `js`

Comment: você poderia me indicar um tutorial, link, algo para ter um norte de como fazer

Answer (score 0):

Usar JavaScript é a melhor maneira de se fazer. JQuery pode te ajudar muito nisso.
Pode seguir esse tutorial [aqui.](https://tableless.com.br/paginacao-com-javascript-e-jquery/)

Exemplos a seguir uso JQuery Bootgrid.

HTML da Grid e depois o JavaScript que alerta sobre o ID selecionado.

```js
$("#grid-selection").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    post: function ()
    {
        /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
        return {
            id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
        };
    },
    url: "/api/data/basic",
    selection: true,
    multiSelect: true,
    formatters: {
        "link": function(column, row)
        {
            return "<a href=\"#\">" + column.id + ": " + row.id + "</a>";
        }
    }
}).on("selected.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function(e, rows)
{
    var rowIds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        rowIds.push(rows[i].id);
    }
    alert("Select: " + rowIds.join(","));
}).on("deselected.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function(e, rows)
{
    var rowIds = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        rowIds.push(rows[i].id);
    }
    alert("Deselect: " + rowIds.join(","));
});
```

```html
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="id" data-type="numeric">ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="sender">Sender</th>
            <th data-column-id="received" data-order="desc">Received</th>
            <th data-column-id="link" data-formatter="link" data-sortable="false">Link</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Através desse endereço: `current=1&rowCount=10&sort[sender]=asc`

Current = significa a página que você está;
rowCount = total de linhas a ser exibidas;
sort[sender] = ordem de listagem crescente;

Usando a lógica você cria a páginação, pode ser tanto no javascript como no back-end.

Segue exemplo em JS

```js
function listItems(items, pageActual, limitItems){
    let result = [];
    let totalPage = Math.ceil( items.length / limitItems );
    let count = ( pageActual * limitItems ) - limitItems;
    let delimiter = count + limitItems;
    
    if(pageActual <= totalPage){
        for(let i=count; i<delimiter; i++){
            if(items[i] != null){
                result.push(items[i]);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    return result;
};
```

Lembrando que se usar a lógica em JS, deve enviar o resultado para o back-end.

A consulta no banco de dados pode ser algo assim, mas tudo isso depende da estrutura do desenvolvimento.

```
SELECT p.id, p.Nome, p.Idade FROM Pessoa p WHERE p.id BETWEEN 1 AND 20
```

Nisso que posso ajudar, vai ter muita informação no Google.
Se alguma coisa ficou confusa, eu edito assim que der.
Fontes: [JQueryBootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/examples#selection)
        [Paginação com JS](https://braziljs.org/blog/criando-um-sistema-de-paginacao-simples-com-javascript/)

Comment: obrigado, você teria algum exemplo para clarear ? se não for pedir muito

Comment: @VictorT. editei a resposta.

Comment: Na verdade tentei fazer sem o select na tabela desejada e o resultado foi apenas a tabela mostrada na tela

Comment: Explique um pouco mais do que você fez, para entender melhor. Para a paginação funcionar você precisa ter um número de registro, se tiver 100 registros vai ter 5 páginas com 20 linhas. Você pode simular, criando uma array com vários registros e mandar exibir na tela.